# ScandiPWA local theme setup

Tags: reactjs, magento2, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to setup ScandiPWA locally following this guide: https://docs.scandipwa.com/hands-on-tutorials/lets-talk-theory

I was following the steps but when I run `npm start` I'm getting the following error:

```
./node_modules/@scandipwa/webpack-i18n-runtime/src/util/localeMap.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:UsersAdamDocumentsCodingscandikesapotlac
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: This is likely due to a bug. ScandiPWA support for Windows occasionally breaks, but hopefully this will get fixed soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue on scandiPWA side but it is alread fixed.